# Execute command with specific routing (ip/iptables)?

Tags: iptables, ip, routing

I saw great solution for binding application based on some routing table alias... not sure now what it was, but for sure with `ip`, `route` or `iptables` tools... anybody knows the procedure? What was the command line (using those) to run process with given routing table?

Comment: Do you mean `ip netns`? A network namespace is more than just a routing table though...

Comment: thanx that was it! :) found the rest

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for [network namespaces](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ip-netns.8.html).

```
ip netns ...
```

You assign specific interfaces as well as processes to one (and only one namespace). Each namespace has its own private routing table, and the processes sending and receiving in that namespace consult the namespace's routing table and only send packets on the interfaces that are members of the namespace.

The only way to get packets from one namespace to another (other than out through the network and back in through another interface) is with special [two-ended pipe interfaces](https://superuser.com/questions/764986/howto-setup-a-veth-virtual-network).